# Android Java - Two socketmessages when sending one

Tags: java, android, sockets, inputstream, outputstream

I send a message over sockets from an android app to a java program. This message is sent with a printwriter.

here is how I send my message from android to java program:

```
out.println("Hello there");
out.flush();
```

This is how I receive the message:

```
while(true){
String msg = in.readLine();

System.out.println("MSG: " + msg);

...some if-statements...
}
```

The output of the System.out.println is:
**MSG: Hello there**
**MSG: null**

How come I get null there? I'm only sending "hello there"..

Help would be appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT:** Actual code of the java program.

```
while (run) {
            String msg = in.readLine();
            String[] parts;  
            String username;
            String password = null;

            System.out.println("MSG: " + msg);

            parts = msg.split("\\*");
            username = parts[0];
            password = parts[1];

            boolean validUser = false;

            validUser = db.authenticate(username, password);

            if (validUser) {
                        db.updateIP(username,                     socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
                        out.println("done");
                        out.flush();
            } else {
                        out.println("loginfail");
                        out.flush();
                        closeSocketConnection();
                }
            }
        }

    private void closeSocketConnection() throws IOException {
        in.close();
        out.close();
        socket.close();
        run = false;
    }
```

Comment: If the input string is `"Hello world"` I would expect `password = parts[1];` to throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Where is `run` defined. What is the entire function in which the `while` loop is contained?

Comment: Ok I know I'm sorry I was not that clear. "Hello world" was just an example in my first pseudocode. Now I send "user*123" and i get
MSG: user*123
MSG: null.

The while-loop is placed in a Handler (which extends thread) and the run variable is defined outside the while-loop but inside the Handler class.

Comment: When asking questions on SO you have to be clear. Pseudo-code and unrelated example input does not work especially when it is not representative of the situation in which you are having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

What is your exit condition for your `while` loop?

It looks to me like it is repeating and `readLine` will return `null` when the end of the stream has been reached causing `MSG: null` to be printed.

**Updated given new information:**

Assuming `user*123` is a valid username/password combo then `closeSocketConnection()` is never called, the loop returns to the top, `readLine` returns `null` and you see your erroneous output. Followed by a `NullPointerException` on `parts = msg.split("\\*");`

Comment: My wile-loop will stop in an if-statement where I close the whole socketconnection to the android app. Also it's not really while(true) but a boolean variable run which becomes false when I close the connection in an if-statement.
How can I avoid this null?

Comment: Please post the actual code you are using. It's not easy to debug code we cannot see.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop should read:

```
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
{
    // ...
}
```

At the moment you're processing the null that indicates end of stream inside the loop, hence you're printing it as a message when it isn't.